# Std::Lock avoids deadlock but this program gets stuck

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, thread-synchronization

All,
Referring to the question in [std::lock still caused deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821512/stdlock-still-caused-deadlock#)

I still couldn't figure what is the problem in the below code. Can somebody please explain the problem and how to fix this? Why does it get hung? Pls help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

std::mutex m1;
std::mutex m2;

void func1()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(m1, std::defer_lock);
    printf("func1 lock m1\n");
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock2(m2, std::defer_lock);
    printf("func1 lock m2\n");
    std::lock(m1, m2);
    printf("func1 std lock\n");

}

void func2()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(m2, std::defer_lock);
    printf("func2 lock m2\n");
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock2(m1, std::defer_lock);
    printf("func2 lock m1\n");
    std::lock(m1, m2);
    printf("func2 std lock\n");
}



int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    std::thread th1(func1);
    std::thread th2(func2);
    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output seen:**
func1 lock m1
func2 lock m2
func1 lock m2
func1 std lock
func2 lock m1
**----- Hung here.**

Why doesn't func2 proceed even though func1 has released both the mutexes?

Comment: _Why does it get hung?_ Because one thread locks both mutexes and does not unlock them. The second thread then waits forever on `std::lock` call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of :

```
std::lock(m1, m2);
```

use :

```
std::lock(lock1, lock2);
```

More details (including an example) can be found on the reference page for [`std::lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock).

### Why does your code hang ?

When you call `std::lock(m1, m2)`, the two mutexes are locked directly. Neither of the `std::unique_lock`s (`lock1` and `lock2`) are aware of this, and thus they can not unlock the mutexes.

So, when `func1` ends both mutexes are still locked, and `func2` cannot proceed past the `std::lock(m1, m2)` line.

### Why does the fixed code work ?

When you call `std::lock(lock1, lock2)`, the `std::unique_lock`s (`lock1` and `lock2`) are aware of this - they now own the locks, and are responsible for unlocking them (which happens when they go out of scope).

So, when `func1` ends both mutexes are unlocked, and `func2` *can* proceed past the `std::lock(lock1, lock2)` line. And all is well.

Comment: In C++17, you may also use `std::scoped_lock l(m1,m2);` without any need for `unique_lock` objects.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica : I didn't mention that because of the c++11 tag the op added, but good point nevertheless.

Comment: You're right, didn't mention C++11 tag. It was just a sidenote.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mistake in my answer. Anyway I think that need to lock 2 mutexes the same time may point onto wrong design.

Comment: @Alex : possibly. Sometimes you *do* need to have multiple resources locked at the same time though.

Comment: @Note that the question is _Can somebody please **explain the problem** and how to fix this? **Why does it get hung?**_ You might want to add some more information.

Comment: @Alex why? sometimes it is necessary to do so. As long as the mutexes are locked in the same order I dont see the problem

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Using the ordering algorithm can lead to performance problems: http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html

Comment: Superb. Got it. Thanks all. The original code was locking the mutexes directly and not via the unique_lock.  std::lock(lock1, lock2) fixed the issue.